# Binary stream detect if protobuf

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I use https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py for detecting GZ and would love to add "protobuf detection" in a similar way, analysing the head bytes of the file.

Is it possible to detect if a binary file is a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) file or not?